# Grid issue on IE8 with Unsemantic

Tags: internet-explorer-8, grid-layout, unsemantic-css

I use Unsemantic for the first time, and I forgot to check my page on IE8. Here is the disaster : http://canapin.com/web/meteo/

Unsemantic is supposed to be IE8 compatible, but my page is messed up, and I can't figure out why.

Any idea? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [its issue tracker](https://github.com/nathansmith/unsemantic/issues/43), since IE8 doesn't support media queries, Unsemantic grid offers a fixed-width layout for it, through a separate css file inclusion:

```
<!--[if (lt IE 9) & (!IEMobile)]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/ie.css?1389034275" />
<![endif]-->
```

Note the conditional comment avoiding the separate css for mobile versions of IE (they are supposed to [support media queries](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries)):

I suppose you can download the source of the separate css from here:
http://unsemantic.com/stylesheets/ie.css

So, if you accept to have an IE8 with fixed-width layout (and it seems very reasonable to me), you don't need a javascript fix ;)

Bye bye!

Answer (score 0):

for IE8 and lower you have to include a shim, which comes with the Unsemantic files.

Include the following code in your head and you should be fine:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="./assets/javascripts/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

So, just point to the html5.js file and this should fix it. Let me know whether this worked for you.

Cheers, Marvin

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I already have this js (from google) loaded on my website, and IE dev tools tells me that the html5 are correctly styled. I also tried with the js included in the unsemantic files.
So I guess the issue comes from somewhere else...

Comment: Okay, I tried on a new empty document, with no html5 markup.
I just have unsemantic-grid-responsive-no-ie7.css with no modifications and two divs with grid-50 class. But I have the same issue on IE8. I still don't get it.

Comment: hmm that really is strange. I guess it would be good to report the bug here: https://github.com/nathansmith/unsemantic/issues